# Dynamically set Outbound Caller ID in Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I have three phone numbers, each one related to a different queue.

And one routing profile where I can set up only one default outbound phone number.

How can I dynamically set appropriate number for the outgoing call depending on what phone number customer called before?

For example: if a customer called on +1234567890, an outgoing call should be from the same number. If called on +1111155555, the outgoing call should be from +1111155555 etc.

I found this guide https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/07/10/amazon-connect-introduces-dynamic-outbound-caller-id/ and also tried to use this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html. But I have no experience with lambda functions and don't know how to use it properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Dmytro, can you please update the question with the outbound calling scenario so I can tell you how to best set the caller ID?  For example, does the agent receive an inbound call from a queue and then they put the caller on hold to make the outbound call or is the inbound call already ended when the outbound call is made?

Comment: Hello @Aossey, sorry for the delay. The outbound call already ended. For example, the agent receives an inbound call and the customer asked to call him back later with additional info. 2 hours later the agent initiates the outbound call to this customer and the number should be the same one that the client has called before